# Error when searching the Content Manager with wildcards

Tags: lucene, tridion, tridion-2011

I have noticed that if I search for certain phrases Tridion Content Manager gives me the following error

```
Unable to get the list of search results.
Unable to process the Search Request. Invalid search query: (*out*) AND RepositoryId:tcm\:0\-4\-1 AND OrganizationalItemAncestorIds:tcm\:*\-135625\-2. maxClauseCount is set to 10240
org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 10240
at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.add(BooleanQuery.java:136)
at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.add(BooleanQuery.java:127)
at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite$1.addClause
[...and so on]
```

In the example above I am searching for the phrase `*out*`. It also fails when I search for the phrase `*a*` and various other smaller wildcard queries. `out*` works fine and `*out*` works fine if I limit the search to just the item titles. It doesn't matter whether I search withing "all publications" or a particular folder. It doesn't even matter if I limit the search results to the minimum (50).

Maybe this is something to do with the number of results returned?

The exact same search works fine on Tridion 5.3, I presume it isn't using lucene?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leading wildcards are not allowed by Lucene (version R5.3 of Tridion used a Verity implementation  that allowed them), due to the way it is indexed and searched.  A leading wildcard effectively causes the index to scan every term for matches, rather than using more typical and performant methods using the index to find matches (see [Lucene FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F))

You can enable this by calling `QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true)`, but I strongly recommend against it in most cases.

A better approach might be to filter on terms that require a leading wildcard, rather than passing them into the query (not really feasible if the leading wildcard term is the only term being searched on)

Also, Lucene provides the [ReverseStringFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/reverse/ReverseStringFilter.html), a filter which indexes all terms in reverse as well.  This would probably be the best way to create your index to enable leading wildcard searching.

Right off, I don't think either of these really handle a query like `*out*` though.  Representing you data as N-Grams might be an option for that (see [NGramTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll just make sure the Tridion 2011 users avoid using a leading wildcard.

Comment: Clear answer, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.